# Java varargs - why are these unacceptable syntax?

Tags: java, compilation, variadic-functions, definitions, signatures

I had this practice test question for my OCAJP8 exam preparation. Can someone please explain why the 'Wrong' ones are wrong? Thanks.

```
Which of the following compile?

Response

Wrong   
public void moreD(String... values, int... nums) {}

Wrong   
public void moreF(String... values, int[] nums) {}

Correct 
public void moreB(String values, int... nums) {}

Correct 
public void moreG(String[] values, int[] nums) {}

Correct 
public void moreA(int... nums) {}

Wrong   
public void moreC(int... nums, String values) {}
```

Comment: There can only be one vararg parameter of a method, and it must be the last parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To quote from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

> Varargs can be used only in the final argument position.